# Teamviewer and Virtualbox do not start on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, teamviewer

Recently I noticed that the teamviewer and virtualbox do not start on my ubuntu 20.04.

I try to start teamviewer by typing `teamviewer` on my console

```
Init...
CheckCPU: SSE2 support: yes
Checking setup...
Launching TeamViewer ...
Launching TeamViewer GUI .
```

But nothing launched.

And for Virtualbox I type

```
$ VBoxManage startvm "win10" --type headless
Waiting for VM "win10" to power on...
VM "win10" has been successfully started.
```

The vm starts but i don't see the Windows screen although I can ping this win10.

Answer (score 2):

- Teamviewer: I don't use it myself so I'm not sure, but are you sure it didn't start ?
  It might be running in the background. Take a look at all running processes with `sudo ps -e` and check if you see it there.
- Virtualbox: You are using the option `headless` which is another way of saying: 
  *Run it, but make sure it runs in the background where I can't see it*

Answer (score 0):

In my case, update/reinstall tv and reboot OS was helpful.

1. `sudo apt remove teamviewer`
2. `sudo apt purge teamviewer`
3. `sudo apt-key add TeamViewer2017.asc`
4. `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list'`
5. `sudo apt update`
6. `sudo apt install teamviewer`
7. `sudo reboot`
8. `teamviewer`

Answer (score 0):

teamviewer and virtualbox use Qt_5.15 and this is the problem in my case,
just install Qt_5.15 and ensure

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
```

existe.